# Unable to determine cause of failure `composer update`

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm upgrading  laravel 5.5 application to 5.6.  I'm getting a significantly long output of conclusions and such that I can't figure out what to do with.  **At the end of the day, what dependency is causing a problem?**

```
$ composer update --no-scripts
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install omnipay/common 2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.8|install omnipay/common 2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.4
    - Installation request for ignited/laravel-omnipay 2.* -> satisfiable by ignited/laravel-omnipay[2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.0 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.1 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.10 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.11 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.12 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.13 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.14 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.2 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.3 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.4 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.5 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.6 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.7 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.8 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.9 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.6.15 requires symfony/http-foundation ~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.3|install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.1|install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.2|install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.4|install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.5|install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.6|install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.7|install symfony/http-foundation v4.0.8
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.2, v5.6.3, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
```

My composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2",
        "alexpechkarev/google-geocoder": "1.*",
        "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "3.*",
        "anlutro/l4-settings": "0.*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.*",
        "bkuhl/easychimp": "~1.0",
        "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "2.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.*",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.5",
        "ignited/laravel-omnipay": "2.*",
        "jackpopp/geodistance": "^1.2",
        "jmikola/geojson": "~1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.*",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "league/html-to-markdown": "^4.4",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "3.*",
        "omnipay/stripe": "2.*",
        "predis/predis": "1.*",
        "ramsey/uuid": "3.*",
        "silber/bouncer": "v1.0.0-rc.1",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^5.0",
        "thomaswelton/laravel-gravatar": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "2.*",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "laravel/browser-kit-testing": "4.*"
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is with `omnipay/stripe` it doesn't actually officially support PHP 7.2 and looks like it [fails on build? not sure, look at \Omnipay\Common\Http::Exception](https://travis-ci.org/thephpleague/omnipay-common/jobs/359433967);  There's an open github issue that may apply to you: https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay/issues/492

Comment: @IsThisJavascript That all makes sense.  But how am I supposed to get to that with these error messages?  What steps did you take?

Comment: I just came across when I was researching your issue, I've never had the same problem myself. I can't be of any more help to you. Maybe if you can push the issue on the git a solution may be provided sooner.

Comment: Upon further reading of the issues on that git page; [This looks like it talks about it in more detail](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay/issues/386)  it does however look that [pinguinjkeke found a solution](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay/issues/483) but the whole thing is in [Russian](https://github.com/pinguinjkeke/omnipay-paymentgateru). Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that **symfony/http-foundation** is required by different packages in version ranges that do not overlap, no version can be found that will satisfy all your dependencies.

More precisely:

- omnipay/common v2.3.2 requires [version 2 or 3](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-common/blob/v2.5.1/composer.json#L32) , not 4
- laravel/framework v5.6.* that you want to update requires [version 4 only](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.6.0/composer.json#L34) and not 2 or 3

"omnipay/common" is required by both [omnipay-stripe](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-stripe/blob/V2.4.7/composer.json#L29) and [laravel-omnipay](https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay/blob/2.3.0/composer.json#L14)

## Using "replace" to ignore "symfony/http-foundation" requirement

You can use [composer replace](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace) to bypass the above constraints and get your updated finished successfully.

So in your composer require, add:

```
    "thomaswelton/laravel-gravatar": "^1.0",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "4.0.8"
}
```

also define the replace property:

```
"replace": {
    "symfony/http-foundation": "*"
},
```

So you are telling composer:

> Do not care about "symfony/http-foundation" at any version(that why you should use "*"), I have took care of it.

That will get your update to complete, but it does not mean it will work, as "omnipay-common" has not been tested to work with "symfony/http-foundation" v4. You can give it a try.

In my opinion, I think you should skip updating and just continue with laravel 5.5, until omnipay/common supports v4 of "symfony/http-foundation", which seems it will happen [soon](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-common/blob/master/composer.json#L45).

## Using "omnipay/common" master branch

The same can be solved by using **"omnipay/common" master branch**, which supports v4. **This is more likely to work**. In that case, do not do the above, but change:

```
"omnipay/common": "dev-master",
```

and

```
"replace": {
    "omnipay/common": "*"
},
```